# How can I speed up solving after a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, sympy

I would like to put different equations into each other and then solve after d. Unfortunately, it takes forever and at some point he tells me that the memory is full. Can I speed this up somehow? Am I doing something wrong?
The command should be correct, because with a simpler formula I have already done the same without inserting into each other.

Here is my module with the equations:

```
## Parameter in SI-Einheiten
p = 103000      # Pa
M_Ar = 0.039948 # kg/mol
R = 8.314       # J/(mol*K)
A_N = 0.0123
gamma = 3*10**(-4)
g = 9.81        # m/s^2
cw2 = 0.45
cw1 = 0.18

# --------

## Eingabe der Temperatur
choice = 1
if choice == 1:
    temp = 298.15
    roh_titan = 4505 # kg/m^3
    eta = 0.0000225
elif choice == 2:
    temp = 2000
    roh_titan = 4000 # kg/m^3
    eta = 0.00012217


# --------

## Berechnung Geschwindigkeit u für allgemein cw
def u_cw(du, u3):
    return (sigma_p()*4/3*du/cw(du, u3)*g)-(u3*10**(-3))**2


# ------

# Berechnung cw-Wert
def cw(d4, u4):
    return 24/re(d4, u4)*(1+0.15*re(d4, u4)**0.687)+0.44


# Berechnung Reynoldszahl
def re(d2, u2):
    return roh_ar()*u2*d2/eta


## Berechnung Dichte Argon
def roh_ar():
    return p*M_Ar/(R*temp)


def sigma_p():
    return roh_titan/roh_ar()
```

And here's my script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pandas as pd
import fw_istgleich_fg_NurEinCw
from sympy import *


print('Datei einlesen')
## Aus Datei lesen mit genfromtxt und ausgeben
data = np.genfromtxt(dateiname3, skip_header=1, usecols=(0,1,4), delimiter='\t', invalid_raise=False, filling_values=0)
print('Datei eingelesen')
xx = data[0::,0]
yy = data[0::,1]
velocity_1d = data[0::,2]


# definiere Dataframe
vel_Coord = {'x':xx,
             'y':yy,
             'velocity': velocity_1d}       # in mm/s, muss im Modul umgerechnet werden!
df = pd.DataFrame(vel_Coord)
print('Dataframe wurde erzeugt')


# Geschwindigkeit in Durchmesser umrechnen
diameter1 = []
diameter2 = []
```

This command should call the equations and then solve them after d:

```
d, geschw = symbols('d, geschw')
result = solve(fw_istgleich_fg_NurEinCw.u_cw(d, geschw), d)  
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are solving essentially the same equation many times, just with different coefficients. It would be more efficient to introduce symbols

```
p, M_Ar, ...,  eta = symbols('p, M_Ar, ... , eta', positive=True)
```

and solve the equation once. Then substitute the floating point constants into the *solution*, with

```
values = {p: 103000, ..., eta: 0.00012217}
result_numeric = result.subs(values)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am solving the equation only one time but directly with the values. But I can try your code...